# Is it possible to specify a custom path for packages.config for nuget?

Tags: nuget

I'm working on a little project and i'm running into an issue which is very likely related to my folder structure.

[My Project](https://github.com/taori/AjaxHub/tree/master/AjaxHub/src)

If possible at all for the folder structure to keep existing like that i would probably need a way to specify which packages.config to load on a per project basis.

I want this structure to ensure unique files without having to maintain references through file links.

However in order for the compiles to work some projects need other framework targets. Now unless i can specify a path to seperate packages.config i am forced to split up my csproj files into seperate folders again? Does anyone know a way around this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple projects in the same directory. NuGet supports that with a packages.config file named after the project:

```
packages.ProjectName.config
```

If your project has a space in it then with NuGet 2 you need to replace the space with an underscore.

```
packages.Project_Name.config
```